# Deploying .Net Web Service on Windows Server 2008 fails

Tags: c#, iis, deployment, windows-server-2008

I am trying to deploy a web service, written in VS2008 on a brand new Windows Server 2008. The same project was deployed successfully countless times on Windows Server 2003.

I have tried deploying in two ways (both works on the older Windows Server 2003):

1. *Publish* the project using Http directly to the IIS server. I receive the following error  : "Could not find a Web server at 'dotnetservtest'. Please check to make sure that the Web server name is valid and your proxy settings are set correctly. If you are sure that everything is correct, the Web server may be temporarily out of service."
2. Create an MSI and running it on the server. Immediately after clicking the file, the installer prints to the screen : "The installer was interrupted before *ApplicationName* could be installed. You need to restart the installer to try again."

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

---

Edit: 
We have managed to solve both problems, thanks to the leads by Alex Stankiewicz.
The first problem could be solved by enabling IIS6.0 on the server.

The scond problem can be solved by installing FrontPage Extensions, as described [here.](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/387/using-visual-studio-2008-with-iis-70/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the installer/setup generator in your vstudio. Version provided with VS2008 knows how to talk to iis6. Try to switch the compatibility of the metabase of your iis7 (on win2008 ) to ii6. So the metabase compatibility must be set to iis6. The other option is to use new installer MS plan to provide with VS2010. The link is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376033(VS.85).aspx)

Alek

Comment: +1 Thanks! I managed to install the MSI by enabling the IIS6 compatibility. However, I would really like to be able to publish the application without having to manually install a MSI every time.